# Move Document from Library to List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

I have a document library in place so that users can bulk upload files. Now, in the edit form I am using 
http://spcd.codeplex.com/
within a CEWP so users don't have to scroll through a 200 item lookup.

However, the library only seems to work on lists, and not the document library (I don't know why, my javascipt ability is extremely limited). And I know the library works and my syntax is correct as I have it working for multiple lists.

So what I would like to do is copy the documents on upload using a SPD workflow, but that is throwing an error (column mismatch probably).

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish the move? Looking for either no code or client side code only.

Or, if someone has an alternate solution for the cascading drop downs.

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a SPD workflow to create a list item and used a hyperlink field to link to the document

Patrick